# Save JSON from API using bashscript

Tags: json, linux, bash, url

I am trying to get multiple files from url, which returns JSON and save them as JSON file.

I have tried the code below:

```
for i in {23..24}
do
wget "https://some url/${i}" > "${i}".json;
done
```

However, it only saves, for example "23" as file which contains the returned json as text, not as "23.json".

Comment: the default behavior of wget is to save to a file, not write to standard outout. Read it's documentation for how to change this or specify the output file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -O option instead to download file with required name.

```
for i in {23..24}
do
wget -O  "${i}".json  "https://some url/${i}" ;

done
```

Or use curl

```
for i in {23..24}
do
curl "https://some url/${i}" > "${i}".json;
done
```